# Как редактировать БД Mysql через Рнр?

Tags: php, mysql

Дана Бд нужно было сделать вывод БД через пхп. Это не составило особой проблемы. Но вот как теперь сделать, чтобы эту же таблицу можно было редактировать и изменения сохранялись (в этой же таблице конечно)?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/research/302421/php-pdo-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите в сторону [phpmyadmin](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin).

> PHPMyAdmin — веб-приложение с открытым кодом, написанное на языке PHP и представляющее собой веб-интерфейс для администрирования СУБД MySQL. PHPMyAdmin позволяет через браузер осуществлять администрирование сервера MySQL, запускать команды SQL и просматривать содержимое таблиц и баз данных. Приложение пользуется большой популярностью у веб-разработчиков, так как позволяет управлять СУБД MySQL без непосредственного ввода SQL команд, предоставляя дружественный интерфейс.